# Вернуть по условию php

Tags: php

Помогите исправить, у меня есть кусок кода

```
return $item->sum === '10' || $item->sum === '20' || $item->sum === '30';
```

а в место этого передать массив и выполнить условие по нему, то есть

```
$array = ['10', '20', '30'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте это: `return in_array($item->sum, $array)`. Он вернет `true`, если есть вхождение `$item->sum` в массиве `$array`.